# How to use return value in PHP

Tags: php

Im sending a mail from one function to another like this

```
sendMail($email) 
    if($result == 1) {
        return redirect('/')->with("msg", $response);
    } else {
        return redirect('/')->with("msg", $badResponse);
    }
function sendMail($email) {
//...
    if($mail->send){    
        $result = 1;
    } else {    
        $result = 2;
    }
    echo $result;
}
```

How do i get the value of `$result` and use it after the function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the result and save it to a variable, rather than just `echo`ing it:

```
$result = sendMail($email);

if($result == 1) {
  return redirect('/')->with("msg", $response);
} else {
  return redirect('/')->with("msg", $badResponse);
}

function sendMail($email) {
  //...
  if($mail->send){    
    $result = 1;
  } else {    
    $result = 2;
  }

  return $result;
}
```